# Looking for a fullwidth slider

Tags: jquery, slider

Hi there Im looking to achieve something like the slider on this website:

http://www.egoargentina.com/en/

The slider should span the full width of the page. I've been looking round and I don't seem to be able to find one. The one on Ego Argentina seems to be custom built so I don't want to use it in case the licencing issues come back at me.

The height needs to stay fixed but the width needs to be fluid. The images do not need to be scaled as they would fade out at the edges.

Answer (score 5):

It will looks something like:

html:

```
<div class="header wrapper">
    <h1>Site header</h1>
</div>
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">1</div>
    <div class="slide">2</div>
    <div class="slide">3</div>
    <div class="slide">4</div>
</div>
<ul class="slider-nav">
    <li><a href="#" >1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Some site content will be here</p>
        <p>Some site content will be here</p>
        <p>Some site content will be here</p>
        <p>Some site content will be here</p>
        <p>Some site content will be here</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="wrapper">&copy; www.mysite.com</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.clear { clear:both; }
.wrapper { width:980px; margin:0 auto; }
.slider { margin:20px 0; height:100px; position:relative;  }
.slider .slide { display:none; background:red; position:absolute; height:100px; width:100%; }
.header { background:#eee; font-size:18pt; }
.content { }
.footer { background:#eee; text-align:center; }

.slider-nav { margin: 0 auto; width:100px; clear:both; } 
.slider-nav li { float:left; margin:0 5px; }
```

js:

```
$('.slider .slide:eq(0)').addClass('active').fadeIn(200);

$('.slider-nav li a').click(function() {    
    var index = $(this).parent().index('li');
    console.log(index);
    $('.slider .slide.active').removeClass('active').fadeOut(200, function() { 
            $('.slider .slide:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active').fadeIn(200);
        });

    return false;
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/GPuh6/16/

Full-screen demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GPuh6/16/embedded/result/

P.S. Autorotating still need to be finished.

**update: autorotation**

```
$('.slider .slide:first').addClass('active').fadeIn(200);

function rotate(index) {
     $('.slider .slide.active').removeClass('active').fadeOut(200, function() { 
         $('.slider .slide:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active').fadeIn(200);
     });   
}

$('.slider-nav li a').click(function() {    
    var index = $(this).parent().index('li');
    rotate(index);
    return false;
});

setInterval(function() {
    var $next = $('.slider .slide.active').next();

    if ($next.length == 0)
        $next = $('.slider .slide:first');

    rotate($next.index());
}, 2000);
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/GPuh6/23/

Full-screen demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GPuh6/23/embedded/result/

Comment: This is good, I can insert the images as part of the .slide elements background and add in the captions inside the element.

Comment: Any idea on how to get it to autorotate / Dynamic Arrows?

Comment: Yep, check the latest update. Highlighting link numbers can be done in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try Nivo Slider- it's a popular jQuery plugin and I have used it many times and found it to be great(http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/). Check it here: http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

The width and height settings depends on what values you give in the CSS. You can give the following values in the css file:

```
.nivoSlider {
             .........
             width:auto; /* Keeps the width fluid, depending on image width */
             height:246px; /* Change this to your images height */
             ..........
}
```

Check the usage instructions here: http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Flow Slider? I think it should be easy to create that effect you want.

[Flow Slider Gallery](http://www.flowslider.com)