# Javascript slider doesn't work locally?

Tags: javascript, html

okay guys, I found a small piece of code on stackoverflow which is for a slidehsow using javascript. But for some reason it doesn't work on my PC. This is the original Post:
[Looking for a fullwidth slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803823/looking-for-a-fullwidth-slider)

it works there but for some reason it doesn't work for me!!

what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.clear { clear:both; }
.wrapper { width:980px; margin:0 auto; }
.slider { margin:20px 0; height:100px; position:relative;  }
.slider .slide { display:none; background:red; position:absolute; height:100px; width:100%; text-align:center; color:#fff; font-size:24pt; }
.header { background:#eee; font-size:18pt; }
.content { }
.footer { background:#eee; text-align:center; }

.slider-nav { margin: 0 auto; width:100px; clear:both; } 
.slider-nav li { float:left; margin:0 5px; }
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.slider .slide:first').addClass('active').fadeIn(200);

function rotate(index) {
     $('.slider .slide.active').removeClass('active').fadeOut(200, function() { 
         $('.slider .slide:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active').fadeIn(200);
     });   
}

$('.slider-nav li a').click(function() {    
    var index = $(this).parent().index('li');
    rotate(index);
    return false;
});

setInterval(function() {
    var $next = $('.slider .slide.active').next();

    if ($next.length == 0)
        $next = $('.slider .slide:first');

    rotate($next.index());
}, 2000);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header wrapper">
    <h1>Site header</h1>
</div>
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">1</div>
    <div class="slide">2</div>
    <div class="slide">3</div>
    <div class="slide">4</div>
</div>
<ul class="slider-nav">
    <li><a href="#" >1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Some site content will be here</p>
        <p>Some site content will be here</p>
        <p>Some site content will be here</p>
        <p>Some site content will be here</p>
        <p>Some site content will be here</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="wrapper">&copy; www.mysite.com    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That page does not appear to include jQuery upon which it depends, try including it.

Comment: Your styles are commented out too.

Comment: @AlexK. sorry if it sounds stupid but how can i include the jQuery in that page? I am fairly new to javascript and jQuery.

Comment: inside <head> put <script src="path-to-js-file"></script>

Comment: but where can I find that path to js file? because theer is nothing mentioned in the original post about the path??!?

Comment: This includes jQuery (from google cdn) and wraps the js in the appropriate ready event which your example is missing; http://jsbin.com/efejin/1/ (click top right for source)

Comment: you can use jquery.js locally if you download it from web, or use hosted on website like: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Alex K. Thank you for the reply. Your example works but it is not autoplay! do you know how to make that example autoplay?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to reference a javascript library (maybe jquery) in your code, but no trace of the library inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery code but where is your reference to the jQuery library?